# finding the centroid of words in a document image

Tags: computer-vision

how to find find centroid of words in a document image ? I have tried doing it using first blurring each word so as to connect characters to form a contour and then using mean in that contour to find centroid . Is there any other method ?

Comment: You have followed the definition of centroid. So, you are in right track. However, the quality of the way you have decided to decide if a prticular contour is a word, depends on your image quality. So, please provide some example images.

Answer (score 0):

Blurring can be a good way but depending on the font you can start blurring words with the words one string above or below. You can consider two more levels of representation of text elements to make your method more robust.

You can go a level lower in your processing and get segments with letters. One can use [MSER](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html?highlight=mser#MSER%20%3a%20public%20FeatureDetector) or connected components or [Stroke Width Transform](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/text_detection.pdf) to find letters. Monitoring the distance between letters will allow you to join them into words. A size of a letters and distance between them within a word can also give you a better idea about the possible distance between words.

You can also go a level higher (in the processing hierarchy) and find strings. Then you can traverse a string making a histogram out of the vertical scan lines willed with letter pixels. The throughs in the histograms will indicate word boundaries. The height of the string can also commensurate with the length of white space between words. Finally, a string as a whole seems to less depend on the peculiarities of the font or capitalization compared to words.